# How to display an error popup or alert message by selecting a conditional dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a filtering dropdowns on hover, where by selecting the country name on hover from the first dropdown the respective destinations will appear in the second dropdown on hover.

Firstly if mouse hovered on the destinations dropdown instead of country, an error message need to be displayed like "select country first".

Here is the complete code.

```js
function changeddl(obj) {
  var text = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;
  var ddl2 = document.querySelectorAll('#iOperation option');
  for (var i = 1; i < ddl2.length; i++) {
    var option = ddl2[i];
    option.style.display = 'none';
    if (text == 'Pick a Country') {
      if (['Pick a Destination'].indexOf(option.text) > -1)
        option.style.display = 'none'

    }

    if (text == 'India') {
      if (['Bangalore', 'Delhi', 'Gujarat', 'Kerala', 'Kutch Desert', 'South Kerala', 'Tamil Nadu Forests', 'Mysore'].indexOf(option.text) > -1)
        option.style.display = 'block'
    }
    if (text == 'Sri Lanka') {
      if (['Sri Lanka', ].indexOf(option.text) > -1)
        option.style.display = 'block'
    }

    if (text == 'Sweden') {
      if (['Sweden'].indexOf(option.text) > -1)
        option.style.display = 'block'
    }
  }
}

var countryArrays = [
  ['Bangalore', 'Delhi', 'Gujarat', 'Kerala', 'Kutch Desert ', 'South Kerala ', 'Tamil Nadu Forests ', 'Mysore '],
  ['Sweden'],
  ['Sri Lanka']
];

function DropNew() {
  var index = document.getElementById("iFunction").selectedIndex - 1;

  if (index >= 0) {
    document.getElementById("iOperation").size = countryArrays[index].length + 1;
  }
}

function DropList() {
  var n = document.getElementById("iFunction").options.length;
  document.getElementById("iFunction").size = 5;
}

function handleSelect(elm) {
  window.location = elm.value;
}
```

```css
option:hover {
  background: #428ffa;
  color: white;
}

#iOperation,
#iFunction {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:10px; float:left">
  <select id="iFunction" name="nFunction" onmouseover="DropList()" onmouseout="this.size=1;" onchange="changeddl(this)">
    <option value="" selected="">Pick a Country</option>
    <option value="">India</option>
    <option value="">Sri Lanka</option>
    <option value="">Sweden</option>

  </select>
</div>

<div style="height: 10px; float: left; margin-left: 50px">
  <select id="iOperation" onchange="location = this.value;" onmouseover="DropNew()" onmouseout="this.size=1;" name="nOperation">
    <option value="" selected="">Pick a Destination</option>
    <option class="hidden" value="https://www.amazon.in/">Bangalore</option>
    <option class="hidden" value="https://www.flipkart.com/">Delhi</option>
    <option class="hidden" value="https://www.snapdeal.com/">Gujarat</option>
    <option class="hidden" value="https://www.paytm.com/">Kerala</option>
    <option class="hidden" value="https://www.amazon.in/">Kutch Desert</option>
    <option class="hidden" value="https://www.flipkart.com/">South Kerala</option>
    <option class="hidden" value="https://www.snapdeal.com/">Tamil Nadu Forests</option>
    <option class="hidden" value="https://www.snapdeal.com/">Mysore</option>
    <option class="hidden" value="https://www.paytm.com/">Sri Lanka</option>
    <option class="hidden" value="https://www.paytm.com/">Sweden</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function changeddl(obj) {
  var text = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;
  var ddl2 = document.querySelectorAll('#iOperation option');
  for (var i = 1; i < ddl2.length; i++) {
    var option = ddl2[i];
    option.style.display = 'none';
    if (text == 'Pick a Country') {
      if (['Pick a Destination'].indexOf(option.text) > -1)
        option.style.display = 'none'

    }

    if (text == 'India') {
      if (['Bangalore', 'Delhi', 'Gujarat', 'Kerala', 'Kutch Desert', 'South Kerala', 'Tamil Nadu Forests', 'Mysore'].indexOf(option.text) > -1)
        option.style.display = 'block'
    }
    if (text == 'Sri Lanka') {
      if (['Sri Lanka', ].indexOf(option.text) > -1)
        option.style.display = 'block'
    }

    if (text == 'Sweden') {
      if (['Sweden'].indexOf(option.text) > -1)
        option.style.display = 'block'
    }
  }
}

var countryArrays = [
  ['Bangalore', 'Delhi', 'Gujarat', 'Kerala', 'Kutch Desert ', 'South Kerala ', 'Tamil Nadu Forests ', 'Mysore '],
  ['Sweden'],
  ['Sri Lanka']
];

function DropNew() {
  var index = document.getElementById("iFunction").selectedIndex - 1;

  if (index >= 0) {
    document.getElementById("iOperation").size = countryArrays[index].length + 1;
  } else {
    $("#popup").show();
  }
}

function hidePopup() {
  $("#popup").hide();
}

function DropList() {
  var n = document.getElementById("iFunction").options.length;
  document.getElementById("iFunction").size = 5;
}

function handleSelect(elm) {
  window.location = elm.value;
}
```

```css
option:hover {
  background: #428ffa;
  color: white;
}

#iOperation,
#iFunction {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:10px; float:left">
  <select id="iFunction" name="nFunction" onmouseover="DropList()" onmouseout="this.size=1;" onchange="changeddl(this)">
    <option value="" selected="">Pick a Country</option>
    <option value="">India</option>
    <option value="">Sri Lanka</option>
    <option value="">Sweden</option>

  </select>
</div>

<div style="height: 10px; float: left; margin-left: 50px">
  <select id="iOperation" onchange="location = this.value;" onmouseover="DropNew()" onmouseout="this.size=1; hidePopup();" name="nOperation">
    <option value="" selected="">Pick a Destination</option>
    <option class="hidden" value="https://www.amazon.in/">Bangalore</option>
    <option class="hidden" value="https://www.flipkart.com/">Delhi</option>
    <option class="hidden" value="https://www.snapdeal.com/">Gujarat</option>
    <option class="hidden" value="https://www.paytm.com/">Kerala</option>
    <option class="hidden" value="https://www.amazon.in/">Kutch Desert</option>
    <option class="hidden" value="https://www.flipkart.com/">South Kerala</option>
    <option class="hidden" value="https://www.snapdeal.com/">Tamil Nadu Forests</option>
    <option class="hidden" value="https://www.snapdeal.com/">Mysore</option>
    <option class="hidden" value="https://www.paytm.com/">Sri Lanka</option>
    <option class="hidden" value="https://www.paytm.com/">Sweden</option>
  </select>
  <div id="popup" class="hidden">Please select country first</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ,thank your so much for your answer, instead of alert message for the complete page, can i get a error popup near the select destination only

Comment: @Saif check now. If you need some explanation just say so :)

Comment: that you so much  this is exactly what i required.

Answer (score 1):

Just check for `selectedIndex`:

```
function DropNew() {
    if(0 === document.getElementById("iFunction").selectedIndex){
        alert('Please select country !');
        return;
    }
     /* TO DO */
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response @Arvind, instead of alert message for the complete page, can i get a error popup near the select destination only.